# Get all edges of a cuboid (3D NumPy array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Having a 3-dimensional numpy array `A` I want to get all the *edges* (imagine this array as a cuboid).

Well, `A[0, 0, :]` would give me one edge, `A[0, -1, :]` second one and `A[:, -1, -1]` yet another one... so all I'd have to do is get all permutations of `0`, `-1` and `:` and use them as indices. Zero and minus one are easy, but how would I do this with colon?

I can solve it the long way, but it's ugly and I bet there is some neat numpy solution to this. Something like:

```
for indices in permutations([0, -1, ':']):
    edge = A[indices]
    ...
```

What I want to do in the end is `numpy.any()` on the set of all edges to see if all edge-values are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is same as `slice(None, None, None)`

`A[0, -1, :]` is same as

```
obj = (0, -1, slice(None, None, None))
A[obj]
```

Comment: The `slice(None, None, None)` part is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!